# How to connect rails with postgresql on docker? Getting: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I followed this tutorial: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rails-on-docker

When I run ...

```
docker-compose run web rake db:create db:setup
```

... I get this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: You'll have to supply us with the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` files.

Comment: @Today They are in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: It sounds like the tutorial is missing a piece of configuration to tell the application where its database is.  You might follow up with that tutorial's authors.  The SO [ask] page has some suggestions for asking here: generally you need to include enough of your own application's code (in this case relevant fragments of the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, and Rails `database.yml` file) for other people to be able to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` use

#### Mac

use `docker.for.mac.host.internal`

#### linux

try https://stackoverflow.com/a/52858101/5616944

#### Windows

use `host.docker.internal`